# bootstrap 3 modal footer align buttons on both edges

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I align buttons in modal's footer so they are on both sides of modal ? Default behaviour sets all buttons near right edge, but I need close button on right and another buttons on left.

Answer (score 6):

You can add class **`pull-left`** to the buttons which you want to align to left.

In the below sample, **`close`** button will be aligned to **`right`** and other buttons aligned to **`left`**.

**Sample footer code:**

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" style="">Save changes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" style="">Save changes1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

**Example:**

```js
$(function () {
 $(".btn").click(function () {
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Launch Demo Modal</a>

<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?
    </p>
    <p class="text-warning">
     <small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small>
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Save changes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Save changes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Phani's answer but now visualized and using non-inline CSS classes.

```js
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
```

```css
.modal .modal-footer button {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```